# VBA Content.Find in Word, how to return value the right of found text

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to modify code from  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174699

which looks in all word documents in a folder and returns an 'x' in columns  if a searched value is found.
The column names are the documents in the folder. The row names are the searched strings.

I would like the routine to return rather a value or a string that is found in a word document to the right or **next to the searched strings**.

This would be a great tool to collect dates, invoice values, names etc. from unstructured data in word documents to excel table.

```
With oDOC.Content.Find

                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = rCell.Value
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False

                .Execute

                If .Found Then

                    'Sheet1.Cells(rCell.Row, lngCol).Value = "x"    , returns an "x" if the word is found.


                End If

            End With
```

The complete code looks as follows:

```
Public Sub SearchDocs()

    Dim oWRD As Object    '** Word.Application
    Dim oDOC As Object    '** Word.Document
    Dim oFound As Object  '** Word.Range

    Dim rCell As Excel.Range
    Dim lngCol As Long

    Dim strFile  As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lngCol = 1

    '** Set oWRD = New Word.Application

    Set oWRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWRD.Visible = True

    '// XL2007 specific
    Sheet1.Range("B2:XFD100000").ClearContents

    strFile = Dir$(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value & "\*.doc?")
    lngCol = 2

    '// loop matching files
    Do While strFile <> vbNullString
        'open
        Set oDOC = oWRD.Documents.Open(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value & "\" & strFile)

        With Sheet1.Cells(2, lngCol)
            .Value = strFile
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 90
            .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 3.35
        End With

        For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

            With oDOC.Content.Find

                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = rCell.Value
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .Forward = False
                .Execute

                If .Found Then
                       'Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                       'Selection.Expand wdWord
                    'Sheet1.Cells(rCell.Row, lngCol).Value = "x"
                    'Sheet1.Cells(rCell.Row, lngCol).Value = .Text
                    Sheet1.Cells(rCell.Row, lngCol).Value = .Parent.Selection.Text

                End If

            End With
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        DoEvents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        lngCol = lngCol + 1


        oDOC.Close
        '// get next file
        strFile = Dir$()

    Loop

    MsgBox "Finshed...", vbInformation

ErrHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    oWRD.Application.Quit

End Sub
```

**I am not able to find in the net, or figure out, how to return a range of the found text and then offset it to return the text/value to the right.** I am aware that offset exists in vba excel.  But how to offset the range of the found string and return the value found in this offset range to excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach might work. Start by initializing a `Range` object to the range you want to search

```
Set oFound = oDOC.Content
```

Then instead of `With oDOC.Content.Find` do

```
With oFound.Find
```

When `.Found = True`, `oFound` will be moved to the found text. You can then move `oFound` by 1 word with something like:

```
With oFound
    .MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    .MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
End With
```

You can adjust `Unit` and `Count` per your requirements. Depending on your needs the related range object methods `MoveEndUntil`, `MoveEndWhile`, `MoveStartUntil` and `MoveStartWhile` may give better functionality. Check out these and other `Range.Move` methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to xidgel. Thanks so much. It works like a charm.

The edited code, according to xidgel's direction may be of help to others, let me paste it:

```
Public Sub SearchDocs()

    Dim oWRD As Object    '** Word.Application
    Dim oDOC As Object    '** Word.Document
    Dim oFound As Object  '** Word.Range



    Dim rCell As Excel.Range
    Dim lngCol As Long

    Dim strFile  As String

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lngCol = 1

    '** Set oWRD = New Word.Application

    Set oWRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWRD.Visible = True



    '// XL2007 specific
    Sheet1.Range("B2:XFD100000").ClearContents

    strFile = Dir$(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value & "\*.doc?")
    lngCol = 2

    '// loop matching files
    Do While strFile <> vbNullString
        'open
        Set oDOC = oWRD.Documents.Open(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value & "\" & strFile)
        Set oFound = oDOC.Content


        With Sheet1.Cells(2, lngCol)
            .Value = strFile
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 90
            .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 3.35
        End With

        For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

            With oFound.Find                   'With oDOC.Content.Find
                Debug.Print rCell.Value

                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = rCell.Text
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .Forward = True
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute

                Debug.Print .Found

                If .Found Then

                    With oFound
                        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        .Expand wdWord

                        .MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
                        .MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=5

                    End With

                    Sheet1.Cells(rCell.Row, lngCol).Value = oFound.Text
                    Debug.Print oFound.Text

                End If

            End With
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        DoEvents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        lngCol = lngCol + 1


        oDOC.Close
        '// get next file
        strFile = Dir$()

    Loop

    MsgBox "Finshed...", vbInformation

ErrHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    oWRD.Application.Quit

End Sub
```